# SQL performance - How to speed up count distincts?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, qliksense

I am new to T-SQL and I have a performance issue. I have a dataset with ~200 Million rows and I count the distinct and NUll values for 7 columns.

I tried two things:

1. Write it into a table. This takes 9 hours.
2. Ultimately I want to load this into QlikSense. Hence, I created a view (5sec) and then loaded it into Qlik in around 7 hours.

I have no clue how this difference is even possible. But is there a way to get a table quickly that contains all this information in less than 4 hours? Could be in any format.

Thanks allot.

*edit*
First of all, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I am not able to share the dataset. The dataset is stored in the SQL database. I indexed it in several ways. This increased the performance but nevertheless, it is still slow.

Comment: Did you try Indexed Views?

Comment: You might add some indexes.

Comment: I agree. Indexes on those columns should help enormously.

Comment: Can you show us the code of the view and how you load it into QLikSense ?

Comment: Also be ware of adding indexes to tables that contain that much records. It might improve speed when querying but can decrease performance significant when inserting/updating/deleting records

Comment: I think you need to edit this question and add a bit more information about exactly what you are trying to do. **Dataset** is quite a general description, so it's very difficult to give advice based on that. What kind of dataset do you have? XML file? .Net DataSet class instance? CSV file?

Comment: Be careful with adding indexes. This reduce f.e. insert performance. And, index requires additional disk space. And, in some cases table may be offline when adding indexes. For example for 5 hours. Be careful.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I am not able to share the dataset. The dataset is stored in the SQL database. I indexed it in several ways. This increased the performance but nevertheless, it is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

you can try "estimated execution plan" which tells "missing indexes"

Comment: Is this some kind of funtion of MSSQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By instead of Distinct and then count. Distinct also sorts up the results

Comment: Both approaches involve implicit sorting. In addition, this is a comment and not an answer. With more reputation, you will be able to add a comment.

Comment: Nope, You're not quite right: "Without an ORDER BY clause, groups returned by GROUP BY aren’t in any particular order. To sort the result of Listing 6.9 by the descending number of books, for example, add the clause ORDER BY “num_books” DESC." See this page to be sure: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30681&seqNum=8